# What does 'corrupted double-linked list' mean

Tags: memory-management, glibc

I've recently gotten the following error from my PHP:

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 42475 said into stderr: "*** glibc detected *** php-fpm: pool www: corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000013fe680 ***"
```

I'm not very bothered by this issue, and not very interested in fixing it. 
But I'm very interested in understanding what this error 'corrupted double-linked list' actually means, because I haven't seen it before. I believe to know what a double-linked list is, but I failed to produce a program that triggers this error.

Could somebody provide me a short snippet of code that causes the glibc to say 'corrupted double-linked list' when I compile and execute it?

Comment: This might be due to various reasons, I suggest that people looking at this post check all the answers below to find their case

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question myself:)

So what I didn't understand was how the glibc could differentiate between a Segfault and a corrupted double-linked list, because according to my understanding, from perspective of glibc they should look like the same thing. 
Because if I implement a double-linked list inside my program, how could the glibc possibly know that this is a double-linked list, instead of any other struct? It probably can't, so thats why i was confused.

Now I've looked at malloc/malloc.c inside the glibc's code, and I see the following:

```
1543 /* Take a chunk off a bin list */
1544 #define unlink(P, BK, FD) {                                            \
1545   FD = P->fd;                                                          \
1546   BK = P->bk;                                                          \
1547   if (__builtin_expect (FD->bk != P || BK->fd != P, 0))                \
1548     malloc_printerr (check_action, "corrupted double-linked list", P); \
1549   else {                                                               \
1550     FD->bk = BK;                                                       \
1551     BK->fd = FD;                                                       \
```

So now this suddenly makes sense. The reason why glibc can know that this is a double-linked list is because the list is part of glibc itself. I've been confused because I thought glibc can somehow detect that some programming is building a double-linked list, which I wouldn't understand how that works. But if this double-linked list that it is talking about, is part of glibc itself, of course it can know it's a double-linked list.

I still don't know what has triggered this error. But at least I understand the difference between corrupted double-linked list and a Segfault, and how the glibc can know this struct is supposed to be a double-linked list:)

Comment: Would be funny if glibs was that smart ;)
"Bad program design" --> *crash*

Answer (score 29):

**Heap overflow** should be blame (but not always) for `corrupted double-linked list`, `malloc(): memory corruption`, `double free or corruption (!prev)`-like glibc warnings.

It should be reproduced by the following code:

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int *p = new int[3];
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.resize(100);
    p[6] = 1024;
    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

if compiled using g++ (4.5.4):

```
$ ./heapoverflow
*** glibc detected *** ./heapoverflow: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000001263030 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7af26)[0x7f853f5d3f26]
./heapoverflow[0x40138e]
./heapoverflow[0x400d9c]
./heapoverflow[0x400bd9]
./heapoverflow[0x400aa6]
./heapoverflow[0x400a26]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f853f57b4bd]
./heapoverflow[0x4008f9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2150398851                         /data1/home/mckelvin/heapoverflow
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 08:02 2150398851                         /data1/home/mckelvin/heapoverflow
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 2150398851                         /data1/home/mckelvin/heapoverflow
01263000-01284000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f853f559000-7f853f6fa000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 201329536                  /lib64/libc-2.15.so
7f853f6fa000-7f853f8fa000 ---p 001a1000 09:01 201329536                  /lib64/libc-2.15.so
7f853f8fa000-7f853f8fe000 r--p 001a1000 09:01 201329536                  /lib64/libc-2.15.so
7f853f8fe000-7f853f900000 rw-p 001a5000 09:01 201329536                  /lib64/libc-2.15.so
7f853f900000-7f853f904000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f853f904000-7f853f919000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 74726670                   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/libgcc_s.so.1
7f853f919000-7f853fb19000 ---p 00015000 09:01 74726670                   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/libgcc_s.so.1
7f853fb19000-7f853fb1a000 r--p 00015000 09:01 74726670                   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/libgcc_s.so.1
7f853fb1a000-7f853fb1b000 rw-p 00016000 09:01 74726670                   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/libgcc_s.so.1
7f853fb1b000-7f853fc11000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 201329538                  /lib64/libm-2.15.so
7f853fc11000-7f853fe10000 ---p 000f6000 09:01 201329538                  /lib64/libm-2.15.so
7f853fe10000-7f853fe11000 r--p 000f5000 09:01 201329538                  /lib64/libm-2.15.so
7f853fe11000-7f853fe12000 rw-p 000f6000 09:01 201329538                  /lib64/libm-2.15.so
7f853fe12000-7f853fefc000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 74726678                   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
7f853fefc000-7f85400fb000 ---p 000ea000 09:01 74726678                   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
7f85400fb000-7f8540103000 r--p 000e9000 09:01 74726678                   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
7f8540103000-7f8540105000 rw-p 000f1000 09:01 74726678                   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
7f8540105000-7f854011a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f854011a000-7f854013c000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 201328977                  /lib64/ld-2.15.so
7f854031c000-7f8540321000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8540339000-7f854033b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f854033b000-7f854033c000 r--p 00021000 09:01 201328977                  /lib64/ld-2.15.so
7f854033c000-7f854033d000 rw-p 00022000 09:01 201328977                  /lib64/ld-2.15.so
7f854033d000-7f854033e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff92922000-7fff92943000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff929ff000-7fff92a00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
[1]    18379 abort      ./heapoverflow
```

and if compiled using clang++(6.0 (clang-600.0.56)):

```
$  ./heapoverflow
[1]    96277 segmentation fault  ./heapoverflow
```

---

If you thought you might have written a bug like that, here is some hints to trace it out.

First, compile the code with debug flag(`-g`):

```
g++ -g foo.cpp
```

And then, run it using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org):

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
==12693== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12693== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12693== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12693== Command: ./a.out
==12693==
==12693== Invalid write of size 4
==12693==    at 0x400A25: main (foo.cpp:11)
==12693==  Address 0x5a1c058 is 12 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==12693==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12693==    by 0x4009F6: main (foo.cpp:8)
==12693==
==12693==
==12693== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12693==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12693==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 412 bytes allocated
==12693==
==12693== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12693==
==12693== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12693== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The bug is located in **==12693==    at 0x400A25: main (foo.cpp:11)**

Comment: What does the vector declaration in the example code have to do with the error?

Comment: @SamuelLi I failed to reproduce the error with this code and g++ 9.3.0, but the Idea should be something like this: when allocating memory, some additional memory is allocated to manage the memory storage, e.g. the pointer to the next block of allocated memory (linked list). The additional vector could be used to generate a second `malloc`ed block and by writing to p[6], the adress of the block containing the internal buffer of the vector can be corrupted. Since I couldn't reproduce this error, the storage format likely changed between g++4.5.4 and g++ 9.3.0

Comment: @schetefan24 I see what you mean, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 16):

This might be due to various reasons, people have mentioned other possibilities and I add my case:

I got this error when using multi-threading (both `std::pthread` and `std::thread`) and the error occurred because I forgot to lock a variable which multiple threads may change at the same time.
This is a runtime error and comes randomly in some runs but not all because ... you know accident between two threads is random.

That variable in my case was a global `std::vector` which I tried to `push_back()` something into in a function called by threads.. and then I used a `std::mutex` and never got this error again.

may help some

Comment: Well, this would be basically the same problem as the one described by @mckelvin's answer. `push_back()` need to allocate memory and to change various internal variables that describe the new state of the vector. Simultaneous changes to them from multiple threads result in an inconsistent state, but then luckily glibc detects that and fails with the error. The only notable difference is that @mckelvin were corrupting those intentionally for example purpose.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who is looking for solutions here, I had a similar issue with C++:
 malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted:

This was due to a function not returning a value it was supposed to.

```
std::vector<Object> generateStuff(std::vector<Object>& target> {
  std::vector<Object> returnValue;
  editStuff(target);
  // RETURN MISSING
}
```

Don't know why this was able to compile after all. Probably there was a warning about it.

Comment: I can't count the hours I've lost to this bone-headed design. The reason it isn't an error is because you might have a function that you know always calls `return` somewhere, but the compiler isn't smart enough to reason about. In that case having an "extra" `return` at the end of the function is unnecessary and wastes memory & code cache. So the compiler is like "hey I'll just hope they did it right". And then your program randomly crashes for incomprehensible reasons in totally unrelated parts of the code.

Comment: By the way I strongly recommend you make it an error by adding `-Werror=return-type`. The reason you probably didn't see the warning is because I would guess `generateStuff()` is in a different translation unit (`.cpp` file) to the place where it was crashing, and if you have incremental compilation that file will never be recompiled while you waste hours fiddling around at the crash site.

Comment: Actually compiler allocate on the heap the variable expected to be returned. This place is ready at the call, but this memory is full of dirty bits, as always when a variable is declared but not initialized. As soon as you try to do something with these dirty bits it will most probably crashes for objects, but for simples types the return value is more or less random (like int : even with dirty bits, an int value is interpretable). In debug mode, some compiler put every bit of memory at Zero so you may have a different behaviour. I fully agree with @Timmmm, this should be an error.

Answer (score 6):

A coworker got this error and found out that somewhere int the code he did this mistake on an element of the list:

```
 std::string listElement = listElement = someObject.getName();
```

obviously instead of :

```
 std::string listElement = someObject.getName();
```

It seems unrelated, but the error was here at every run, we could reproduce it after cleaning everything, and changing only this line solved the problem.

Hope it helps someone one day....

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this error in some code where someone was calling exit() in one thread about the same time as `main()` returned, so all the global/static constructors were being kicked off in two separate threads simultaneously.

This error also manifests as `double free or corruption`, or a segfault/sig11 inside `exit()` or inside `malloc_consolidate`, and likely others.  The call stack for the malloc_consolidate crash may resemble:

```
#0  0xabcdabcd in malloc_consolidate () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0xabcdabcd in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xabcdabcd in operator delete (...)
#3  0xabcdabcd in operator delete[] (...)
(...)
```

I couldn't get it to exhibit this problem while running under valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer in case you were programming something with GTK+ libraries, which produces the same error so maybe it will help others if a search engine brings you here:

If you are writing GTK code, and if you call a GTK function from another pthread outside of the main thread, then you could get a double-free corruption because GTK's main loop is not thread-safe.