# C++ - Smallbin double linked list corrupted

Tags: c++, vector, malloc, stdvector

I need to create a vector of doubles. The problem is, I cannot do that if there are more then 3 values.

**My code:**

```
std::vector <double> tmp {12, 2, 3, 24, 4, 6};
```

**ERROR:**

```
malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x0000000000992400 ***
```

I've never seen this error before. I know it's something about "double deallocation", but I have no idea, why is this happening during vector creation.

Do you know, what's the problem and how should I fix it?

Comment: Corruption errors might jump on code that has nothing to do with it. I'd say the error lies in another part of your code, somewhere around a call to malloc. Ring any bells?

Comment: Have a look at these topics, they should help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897157/what-does-corrupted-double-linked-list-mean

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, it works fine.
May be the rest of program contains bugs.

Error "smallbin double linked list corrupted" is happened when memory used by glibc variables is incorrectly modified from user part of program.

The best tool for detecting such problems is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html), use it!
It really helps to debug crazy program behaviour.