# "gdb" and "valgrind" execute binary in different way?

Tags: debugging, gdb, valgrind, heap-corruption, memory-corruption

My program got error about heap memory corruption.

```
osboxes@osboxes:/mnt/hgfs/VM_Shared/ISSUES/_[02]$ ./shuf /dev/null
*** Error in `./shuf': corrupted double-linked list: 0xb7f01ac0 ***
```

While debugging using only gdb, I come across `valgrind`. (thanks to [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897157/what-does-corrupted-double-linked-list-mean))
And...I got log using `valgrind`.

*(Sorry for the long log, I was going to abbreviate it before questioning but I was afraid that I might miss out some information needed for analysis. )*

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/Desktop/VM_Shared/ISSUES/_[02]$ valgrind --run-libc-freeres=no ./shuf /dev/null
==23373== Command: ./shuf /dev/null
==23373== 
==23373== Invalid read of size 4
==23373==    at 0x40B7859: _IO_file_close_it@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:178)
==23373==    by 0x40B4AE6: freopen64 (freopen64.c:49)
==23373==    by 0x804EECF: ??? (shuf.s:22773)
==23373==  Address 0x20 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==23373== 
==23373== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==23373==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x20
==23373==    at 0x40B7859: _IO_file_close_it@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:178)
==23373==    by 0x40B4AE6: freopen64 (freopen64.c:49)
==23373==    by 0x804EECF: ??? (shuf.s:22773)
==23373==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==23373==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==23373==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==23373==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==23373==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==23373== 
==23373== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23373==     in use at exit: 2,020 bytes in 31 blocks
==23373==   total heap usage: 32 allocs, 1 frees, 2,025 bytes allocated
==23373== 
==23373== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23373==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23373==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23373==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23373==    still reachable: 2,020 bytes in 31 blocks
==23373==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23373== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==23373== 
==23373== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23373== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

***Problem :***

`valgrind` said **invalid read** happened at `178 line in fileopc.c`.
However, I found this program never went to `178 line in fileopc.c` while being debuged by `gdb`!
Control flow went in different way like below.

```
pwndbg> 
176 in fileops.c
────────────────────────────[ DISASM ]────────────────────────────
   0xb7e7184f <_IO_file_close_it+63>     mov    edx, dword ptr [ebx + 0x68]
   0xb7e71852 <_IO_file_close_it+66>     test   edx, edx
 > 0xb7e71854 <_IO_file_close_it+68>   ✔ jle    _IO_file_close_it+151 <0xb7e718a7>
    ↓
   0xb7e718a7 <_IO_file_close_it+151>    push   0
   0xb7e718a9 <_IO_file_close_it+153>    push   0
   0xb7e718ab <_IO_file_close_it+155>    push   0


pwndbg> 
185 in fileops.c
────────────────────────────[ DISASM ]────────────────────────────
   0xb7e7184f <_IO_file_close_it+63>     mov    edx, dword ptr [ebx + 0x68]
   0xb7e71852 <_IO_file_close_it+66>     test   edx, edx
   0xb7e71854 <_IO_file_close_it+68>     jle    _IO_file_close_it+151 <0xb7e718a7>
    ↓
 > 0xb7e718a7 <_IO_file_close_it+151>    push   0
   0xb7e718a9 <_IO_file_close_it+153>    push   0
   0xb7e718ab <_IO_file_close_it+155>    push   0
```

***Problem(cont.) :***

As you can see, control flow didn't reached `178 line in fileopc.c`, where `valgrind` said bug nested in.
Instead, control flow just jumped from `176 in fileops.c` to `185 in fileops.c` directly.

***Question :***

What is happening in here?
Why control flows are different between `valgrind` and `gdb`?
Is it because those two tools use different way in spawning the inspected program?

Answer (score 1):

> What is happening in here?

From [valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.exit_errors):

> **Programs run OK on Valgrind, but at exit produce a bunch of errors involving __libc_freeres and then die with a segmentation fault.**
>
> When the program exits, Valgrind runs the procedure __libc_freeres in glibc. This is a hook for memory debuggers, so they can ask glibc to free up any memory it has used. Doing that is needed to ensure that Valgrind doesn't incorrectly report space leaks in glibc.
>
> The problem is that running __libc_freeres in older glibc versions causes this crash.
>
> Workaround for 1.1.X and later versions of Valgrind: use the --run-libc-freeres=no option. You may then get space leak reports for glibc allocations (please don't report these to the glibc people, since they are not real leaks), but at least the program runs.

Note that while the text above talks about older GLIBCs, this can also happen in programs that corrupt GLIBC internal state, which is apparently the case here.

> Why control flows are different between valgrind and gdb

GDB does not call `__libc_freeres`, Valgrind does. (There are many other subtle differences, but this one is the most likely explanation for observed crash.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Using `--run-libc-freers=no` option, I could mute the second error which was about __libc_freeres. (Edited the log above) However, I still have no idea about the *invalid read* on `fileops.c:178` issue that I mentioned at the question... Although the issue isn't related to glibc freer (can see in the above call stack), the control flow is still different with `gdb`... Is this another issue on `valgrind`?