# Error in `<unknown>': corrupted double-linked list: 0x011eb8e0 happens Occasionally when calling free

Tags: c, pos

I have a problem with `free`.

I test my code in online compiler but everything is OK. However in my device (which is a POS) it rises exception when calling free. It frees two of 4 variables and then rise exception.

My real Code for device:

```
    char **MenuItems = malloc (MAX_PACKETS * sizeof(char *));

    struct packetInfos * packets = (struct packetInfos *)malloc(sizeof(struct packetInfos)*MAX_PACKETS);      
    size = getPacketNames(groupId,packets,MenuItems);
...
...
...
    TRACE(("====size %d",size));
    for(;i<size;i++) {
        TRACE(("====%d=",i,MenuItems[i]));
        free(MenuItems[i]);
    }

    free(MenuItems);
```

gives me:

```
[src/menu.c][NetChargeMenu_L3][1637]>>>====size 4
[src/menu.c][NetChargeMenu_L3][1639]>>>===counter=0  address=34259480
[src/menu.c][NetChargeMenu_L3][1639]>>>===counter=1  address=34260528
```

Sometimes it frees all variables but give me the following error and freeze everything:

```
Error in `<unknown>': corrupted double-linked list: 0x011eb8e0
```

my program is something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 16

int getPacketNames(char **names){
    
    int limit = 4;
    int i = 0;
    
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++) {
        if(i==limit)
            break;
            
        names[i] = malloc(64);
        sprintf(names[i],"random text %d",i);
    }
    
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    
    int i=0;
    int size=0;
    
    char **MenuItems = malloc (MAX * sizeof(char *));
    
   size = getPacketNames(MenuItems);
    
    // do something
    
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
            
        free(MenuItems[i]);
    }
    
    free(MenuItems);

    
    return 0;
}
```

I read this post ([What does 'corrupted double-linked list' mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897157/what-does-corrupted-double-linked-list-mean)) by cannot find a useful hint for my code in C.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The first code block calls a different `getPacketNames()` with 3 args; without seeing that version we'd have to guess.  One possibility: maybe `free()` is being called with a bad pointer; try allocating `MenuItems` with a `calloc()` and check if each pointer is valid before calling `free()`.  Also consider adding error handling for any failed allocation.

Comment: @Milag using `calloc` was a nice comment. Thanks. I change them to `calloc` but the problem exist. I used `getPacketNames` with right parameters in my program but there is no need to other parameters in provided test program.

Comment: Small test program works fine at limit 4, also without limit at MAX 16.

Comment: Yes! It works for me too but not work when running in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is for `malloc` memory not for `free` it. I used **fixed length** in allocation! Before I used dynamic size for allocating. However allocating dynamic size memory must not be a problem, but using fixed size allocation maybe solve other problems such my problem.

My previous code (With problem when free):

```
struct packetInfos{
    int id;
    char name[64];
    long amount;
};


void getOperatorNames(char *names[]) {

    int i=0;

    for(; i<MAX; i++) {
            sprintf(packets[i].name, "%s", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2));
            names[i] = malloc(strlen(packets[i].name) + 1); // the cause of problem in free
            strcpy(names[i], op[i].fname);
    }
}
```

My current code (Without problem):

```
void getOperatorNames(char *names[]) {

    int i=0;

    for(; i<MAX; i++) {
            sprintf(packets[i].name, "%s", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2));
            names[i] = malloc(64);
            strcpy(names[i], op[i].fname);
    }
}
```